# Randomly execute 35 Batch files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have 35 batch files in same folder. All batch files have different names and codes inside, i want to create batch file from where i can run 35 batch files randomly with out knowing their names or any characteristics. i created this batch file

```
@echo off
    :loop
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    if exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\converted\*.bat" (
    for %%b in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\converted\*.bat") do (
    set /a n=!random! %%35+1 
    start "" /w "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\!n!.bat" "%%b"
    ping -n 20 localhost >nul
    del "%%b"
    )
    )
    ping -n 60 localhost >nul
    goto :loop
```

but in this case i need to change all batch files name which is not recommended.looking for solution.

Comment: Run all 35 bat files in a random order? Or randomly run files for as long as you want, where some files may execute multiple times, and others not all?

Comment: yap this is correct "randomly run files for as long as you want" . multiple time run is also no issue

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to randomly run the master script that randomly selects the batch file. The easiest solution is to hang a "scripts" folder off the folder where your master script is, and put your 35 bat scripts there.

The following solution will work with any number of scripts - it is not limited to 35. Pass the number of random runs as the first and only parameter. If not provided then it defaults to 100.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Establish the number of runs from the first parameter. Default to 100 if not provided
set "runCount=%~1"
if not defined runCount set runCount=100

:: Set the current directory to the "scripts" folder at the location of this running script
pushd "%~dp0scripts"

:: Define numbered variables to hold all file names, and establish the total number of files
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%A in ('dir /b *.bat^|findstr /n "^"') do set "file_%%A=%%B" & set /a cnt=%%A

:: Randomly run one of the files %runCount% times
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 %runCount%) do (
  set /a "n = !random!%%cnt + 1"
  for %%N in (!n!) do call !file_%%N!
)

popd
```

Comment: Error during execution : 'Al' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: @shikhahiya - That string token never appears in my code, so it must be an error coming from one of your batch scripts that is randomly called. That should be a fairly obvious thing for you to investigate. I tested my code, and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@echo off
pushd "Directory"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a r=%random% %% 35 + 1
set n=0
:loop
set /a n=n+1
if !n!==35 goto :eof
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b *.bat') >t.txt
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" <t.txt ^| find '!r!'") Do "%%~a"
goto loop
```

Comment: error :  The system cannot find the path specified.
> was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
Set Prog_Dir=%~dp0

CD %Prog_Dir%\Subfolder

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=0

:reset

REM - Dual random comparison IF Check used to thoroughly randomise the launch of .Bats
REM - Check Call and reset loop used to ensure exactly 35 .Bats launched.

For %%c IN (*.bat) DO (
                Set /a rand1=!random! * 35 / 32768 +1
                Set /a rand2=!random! * 114 / 32768 +1
                IF "!rand1!"=="!rand2!" (
            Call :CHECK
            START "" %%c
    )

)

GOTO reset

:CHECK
Set /a count+=1
IF !count!==36 GOTO end
GOTO :EOF

:end
ECHO 35 batches randomly Launched.
pause
exit
```

Comment: the value ranges for Random and the GTR than on lower values Ensures a truly random execution of any given Bat from the For variable. No clustering / favoring the launch of any given batch.

Answer (score 0):

i got this code, but it will randomly select and run all file in a folder and subfolder, it works for me, just take your 35 .bat files and put them in a folder, you just need to loop the program with another batch, its infinite rnd open tho

this is a file.bat

```
@echo off & setlocal

 set "workDir=C:\DVDCOVERS"

 @set /a "rdm=%random%"
 set /a "rdm=%random%"

 pushd "%workDir%"

 set /a "counter=0"
 for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ^|find "."') do call :sub1

 set /a "rdNum=(%rdm%*%counter%/32767)+1"

 set /a "counter=0"
 for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ^|find "."') do set "fileName=%%i" &call :sub2
h.
 popd "%workDir%"

 goto :eof

 :sub1
 set /a "counter+=1"
 goto :eof

 :sub2
 set /a "counter+=1"
 if %counter%==%rdNum% (start "" "%fileName%")
 goto :eof
```

and then create another .bat file

```
@echo off

:start_rnd
start file.bat
goto :start_rnd
```

its not as clean tho and u might need to file bind them if u want them to be together all the time